# Cannot read property of push undefined? Even though I am pushing comment to comments array why am I receiving this error?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, push

I am posting comment to /arms/:id/comments as shown below but always getting the error cannot read property of push undefined

```js
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  arms.findById(req.params.id, function(err, armsFound) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect("back");
    } else {
      comments.create(req.body.comment, function(err, comment) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.redirect("back");
        } else {
          comment.author.id = req.user._id;
          comment.author.username = req.user.username;
          comment.save();
          arms.comments.push(comment);
          arms.save();
          req.flash("success", "Successfully added comment");
          res.redirect("/arms/" + arms._id);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

arms schema
In arm Schema comments is an array and every where on internet including stackoverflow I found that if 
I am pushing something to array then it is ok otherwise if it is anything else then it will give error.
I also read something on stackoverflow which suggested me to use the actual word(from which i m requiring comment schema) for pushing which in my case is "comments" so I wrote "comments" instead of the below code where there is "comment" written but it didn't work too

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const armSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: String,
  image: String,
  description: String,
  owner: {
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User"
    },
    username: String,
  },
  comments: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Comment"
  }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("arms", armSchema);
```

Comment Schema

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  author: {
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User"
    },
    username: String
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like in your code, `arms` is a model, not a document so the `arms.comments` is undefined. Change it to `armsFound` that's in the callback of your `findById()` will solve the problem. Something like this:

```
armsFound.comments.push(comment);
armsFound.save();
```

Comment: bro it worked but i ran into another same problem i m receiving this error " Cannot read property 'comments' of null"

Comment: That's because there's no document match the query so `armsFound`  is null

Comment: which question are you reply to?the one in the post or the one which is in the comment which is "Cannot read property 'comments' of null"  well reply to the comment one plz add some detail i m unable to understand

Comment: Because in your db, there is no document with _id match your `req.params.id` so the result of `arms.findById(req.params.id...` will be null. That's cause the error " Cannot read property 'comments' of null".

Comment: bro tell me what should I write in place of what sorry I know it is too dumb but i just can't understand the actual problem.My data base does contain the id which i m trying to find through find one and this line armsFound.comments.push(comment); is causing problem but i don't know y isn't armsFound an object of arms schema? or what ? I m really confused

Comment: What's the result of `console.log(armsFound)`? If it's null then can you show your updated code?

Comment: comment.author.id=req.user._id;
                    comment.author.username=req.user.username;
                    comment.save();
                    console.log(armsFound);
                    armsFound.comments.push(comment);
                    armsFound.save();
                    req.flash("success","Successfully added comment");
                    res.redirect("/arms/"+arms._id);

Comment: If your db does contain the id which you trying to find then I can't understand why `armsFound` is null.